# How to create flutter app's offline and online

Tags: mongodb, flutter, sqflite, offlineapps

i am just looking for ideas about how to make the app work in online and offline modes(it is a todo app and it should work online and offline both)
I have a todo app that stores the data in sqflite database(locally on the phone) when the app goes online I want the data to be synced with my online database for online database i am using from mongodb. i am just looking for suggestions and also i want to ask which offline database is fine beside of mongode, Hive or sqflite.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a shared_prefernce library and create a function if phone not connected to wifi return null else if connected use socket emit and clear local storage

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's [Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/realm) supports the sync feature, however this would lock your application to the MongoDB's Atlas hosted Database.